# Fancybox is displaying a blank page with IE7

Tags: youtube, internet-explorer-7, fancybox, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to load a YouTube video with Fancybox. It's working with all the browsers but it seems to have problem with IE7, it only shows a blank white page. I don't know what I've done wrong here, I tested there example online and it work with IE7, http://fancybox.net/blog. I also took my code from them.

So here's my markup on the homepage (where the video is located):

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqC3tk_-e7g" title="The Problem" id="homevideo1">
    <span class="playButton"></span>
    <img width="170" src="/images/all/video-image1.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="videoTitle">The Problem</div>
</a>
```

and, this is my script for the video:

```
SetupVideos = function(){
    $("#homevideo1").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 740,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

It might be something to do with CSS, I'm not too sure... But I haven't touch the .css that comes with the plug-in at all

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your jquery click event in document ready, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#homevideo1").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'         : 740,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {'wmode':'transparent','allowfullscreen':'true'}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Try it live [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jFwzt/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried it just in case but that's unfortunately not the source of my problem. Actually, the Fancybox plug-in and the Youtube video works on every other browsers than IE7.

Comment: Then the problem is from another part of the code you did not post. Probably in the use of SetupVideos() because I tested your code with IE7. That's the only IE browser I could use when I anwered. And it also work in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Synotte,

I too had problems with IE7 (not YouTube, but video embedding).

Removing the padding from the map worked for me, for some reason it was reducing the width of the video to zero.

May not be your issue, but worth a try.

Adam